# How to advance text in text RPG jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a small text RPG, I have some characters who say multiple lines of text. The current way I replace the text is the following.

HTML

```
<div class="textarea"></div>
```

JS/jQuery

```
$('.textarea')
    .delay(1000)
    .text("Hello Brave Adventurer Blah blah blah")
    .fadeIn();
```

The issue therefore lies in the next text block....If I write a new .text(), the program just brings up the bottom most text box without displaying the other

Example:

```
  $('.textarea')
        .delay(1000)
        .text("Hello Brave Adventurer Blah blah blah")
        .fadeIn()
        .fadeOut()
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeIn()
        .text('new text')
```

then "new text" displays and the first text "Hello Br..." never shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like that:

```
$('.textarea')
    .hide()
    .text("Hello Brave Adventurer Blah blah blah")
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).text('new text')})
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).text('another new text')})
    .fadeIn(1000)
```

See an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ghuLa48z/1/)

Comment: That's it! Thank you =)!

Answer (score 0):

If you ask jQuery to `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` at the same time, what would you want it to do?

Instead, try using a callback function, like this:

```
.fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        // etc...
    })
})
```

Comment: But then you will end up with the infamous callback pyramid (callbacks inside callbacks inside callbacks)

Comment: True, not a problem if he only has those 2 messages. Ideally he would set up a function so it's just a single function call to display/enqueue a message